# Filter out Bad Words From a Text File In Python

Tags: python, filter, profanity

I am wanting to read the contents of a text file and filter out the bad word from it.
{UPDATED} So I updated my python file after what you told me but right now I am getting a no module error. When I run pip3 install profanity_filter it gives me a big error.[image]

I researched and found Profanity but it is not working

```py
from profanity_filter import ProfanityFilter
pf = ProfanityFilter()

with open(input("Enter the name Of Your File"), "r") as myFile:
           j = myFile.read()
filtered = pf.censor(j)
print(filtered)
```

Here is the error I get when I try to run my file
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the examples at https://pypi.org/project/profanity-filter/#basics? Do you see a difference from how you're trying to use it?

Comment: I want to upload a file that has bad words and pass in the file into my function which will call the ProfanityFilter instance on it and censor bad words so that I get a clean string of text. I do not want to put them in an array because you will be running at 0.01 runtime speed

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation about getting the list of bad words from a file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of the class, and then call its `censor()` method.

And the argument has to be a string, not a list of strings. Call `read()` instead of `readlines()` to get the entire file as a single string.

```
from profanity_filter import ProfanityFilter
pf = ProfanityFilter()

with open(input("Enter the name Of Your File"), "r") as myFile:
   j = myFile.read()
filtered = pf.censor(j)
print(filtered)
```

Comment: I updated what you told me but still getting an error. saying no module right now instead. So I ran a pip3 and it gives an error I tried to see if was install using pip3 freeze and still it wasn't listed. I updated all my packages and uninstalled and reinstalled python and it is still giving me an error. Thank you so much though @Barmar

Comment: If you weren't getting that error before, I don't understand why you would start getting it with my changes.

Comment: Do you know of any library similar to this that I can use that filters bad words

Comment: I don't know anything other than what I can find with google.